# Zero or one association in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, belongs-to, has-one

I am writing a Ruby on Rails application that has two models - User and Farm. A User is considered a farmer if their farmer field is set to true. However, there is no seperate class for farmers.

A User may have either one farm, or none at all. (I believe this is called a zero or one relationship). If I put:

```
has_one :farm
```

in the User model and

```
belongs_to :user
```

in the Farm model, this would create a one-to-one relationship between Users and Farms and mean that every User has a Farm. If I did the above, every User would have a Farm, and that would not make much sense since there are certain Users who cannot have a Farm.

In short, what I want is for a User to have a Farm only if their farmer boolean is set to true. Otherwise, the relationship shouldn't exist. Is their a way to do this using ActiveRecord the way it is meant to be used?

Comment: you could use validations ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations-overview

Comment: Validation is the way to go yeah

Comment: So I should create the farm as a regular field and not using any of the association helpers? And then create a farm only if the validation "farmer == true" passes?

Comment: Using an association is fine. It's not because you declare it that you have to fill it. It can be empty

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto will it impact the size/performance of the db if we have lots of Users with nil Farm associations?

Comment: Nope, there wont be an empty entry on the Farms table for each user who isn't a farmer, so its ok to do it that way.

Comment: Will be an empty farm entry for every user in the User table?

Comment: Yeah but a null entry in SQL is like peanuts ... don't worry about it unless you have a lot of them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can has\_one association be used when the model has one or zero instances of another model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005296/can-has-one-association-be-used-when-the-model-has-one-or-zero-instances-of-anot)

Answer (score 15):

has_one doesn't mean that you must have one related entity(here farm). has_one is used for relation where we have 0 or 1 linked records.

You may find the similar discussion here.

[Can has_one association be used when the model has one or zero instances of another model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005296/can-has-one-association-be-used-when-the-model-has-one-or-zero-instances-of-anot)