# Can has_one association be used when the model has one or zero instances of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, has-one

RailsGuides says:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
A has_many "association indicates that each instance of the model has zero or more instances of another model."

"A has_one association also sets up a one-to-one connection with another model, but with somewhat different semantics (and consequences). This association indicates that each instance of a model contains or possesses one instance of another model."

Does that mean if I want to set up an association that each instance of the model has zero or one instance of another model, the best way is to use has_many and not has_one? What will be the problems I'll encounter if I use has_one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`has_one` is correct - the relationship that's set up is not mandatory unless you add your own [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations-overview) to it.

To make it a bit clearer -

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :author

end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post 

end
```

With no validations, a given `post` can have an author (but not more than one) - however an author is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you define specific validations, `has_one` just prevents you from having more than one object associated to your model.
Zero is ok.